# no wifi adapter detected by Bodhi

Tags: networking, wifi, system-installation, macintosh, bodhi

[Installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/326307/112208) `bodhi-4.5.0-64` onto a 2008 Macbook, 4.1 and am not seeing wireless options.

Do I need to install something from apt first in order for Bodhi to pick up the built-in wifi adapter?  The "network connection" GUI only shows the physical ethernet NIC.

diagnostics:

```
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:436a] (rev 13
)
        Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Imac 8,1 Wired Ethernet Adapter [11ab:00ba]
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$ sudo lshw -C net
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:90500000-90503fff memory:90000000-900fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 13
       serial: 00:1f:5b:e9:5c:de
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.51 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:90400000-90403fff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:90420000-9043ffff
thufir@bot:~$
```

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1923762

```
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

ens5      no wireless extensions.

thufir@bot:~$
```

Comment: What is the output of *lspci -vnn | grep -i net* and of *sudo lshw -C net*? Most likely you are missing the driver and/or the firmware for the driver for your wireless card, the commands above help identifying both the card and what is missing.

Comment: pardon, @MariusMatutiae, didn't have any connectivity yesterday.  thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed:

```
thufir@bot:~$ 
thufir@bot:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wls4      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"dfskflsdj"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: C0:3F:0E:8B:4D:04   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

ens5      no wireless extensions.

thufir@bot:~$
```

history of commands:

```
   14  sudo lspci
   15  spci -vnn | grep -i net 
   16  sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i net 
   17  sudo lshw -C net
   18  iwconfig
   19  sudo apt install wireless-tools
   20  iwconfig
   21  sudo  apt install firmware-b43-installer
   22  iwconfig
   23  sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
   24  iwconfig
```

not quite sure whether it was one specific install, or they were all required -- but it's working.