# how to optimize Ubuntu for older hardware

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, kernel-modules, macintosh, bodhi

Partly to go with the herd, partly to be more towards the cutting edge, I'd prefer Ubuntu 18.04 over Bodhi Linux.  Bodhi [boots reasonably quickly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446093/17056), logs in well, etc -- everything it's intended for.  Clearly, out of the box Ubuntu bogs down this old MacBook.

Having installed Ubuntu, can I perhaps pare down the system in some way?  Remove some kernel modules?

Of course, the Moksha [desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhi_Linux) is probably a huge factor.

While I'm not entirely adverse to trying Xubuntu, Puppy Linux, et. al., I'd like to stick with either Ubuntu, or, if that's not workable, then Bodhi.

System:

```
thufir@bot:~$ 
thufir@bot:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
04:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller (rev 61)
thufir@bot:~$
```

Ubuntu Server seems to install differently on Macbooks -- but maybe it's a UEFI problem:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/326439/112208

Comment: How old is the macbook ?  Which version of Ubuntu?  Avoid the heavyweight desktop environments (gnome, kde, anything with 3d acceleration and massive eye candy) and you should be fine.

Comment: I think it's a Macbook 4.1 from 2008 -- but I'm not positive.

Comment: I just want to point out that you can use XFCE with Ubuntu, too. No need to install a different distro to get rid of Gnome 3 (or Unity).