# Bodhi clean install hangs on splash screen

Tags: boot, grub, hardware, macintosh, bodhi

Having some issues installing Bodhi onto a MacBook era 2008.  Right now it's hung with the splash screen for the first boot.  Only the other day this laptop ran Bodhi fine, but now I'm stuck in a loop of re-installing.  (I tried Ubuntu yesterday, which was too much for this system, so am going back to Bodhi.)

My concern is that interrupting the splash screen will [again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/326878/112208) result in GRUB issues.  To re-iterate, this laptop ran Bodhi fine just a few days ago.

Hardware [is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446093/17056):

```
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:436a] (rev 13
)
        Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Imac 8,1 Wired Ethernet Adapter [11ab:00ba]
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$
thufir@bot:~$ sudo lshw -C net
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:90500000-90503fff memory:90000000-900fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 13
       serial: 00:1f:5b:e9:5c:de
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.51 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:90400000-90403fff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:90420000-9043ffff
thufir@bot:~$
```

This laptop has now been hung for at least five minutes just booting Bodhi...somehwat randomly, `command`-`d` initiated a reboot to the same splash screen.  interspersed with hard drive errors about flip done.  But then, eventually, logs in...

I don't know what's going on.  Hard drive failure?

Comment: It did eventually install, but doesn't always shutdown cleanly.  The recipient also just wasn't thrilled with the GUI.

Comment: I think it was resolved by removing ??xconf?? intel package..